# How do I calculate total payments by year in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I've created the following pivot table.  Now I would like to display the Total of Payments A-D by Month (across) and year (down).  I realize I can go to my data an manually create a 5th Payment that is comprised of Payments A - D, but I'm trying to avoid that approach.  I tried creating a calculated fields and items, but that did not yield the result I'm looking for.

I guess another way of saying this is that how can I display a column grand (not displayed) column by Year?

[image]

Comment: Can you use SUMIFS()?

Comment: That's the manual (non pivot table) approach I was trying to avoid. It just seems to me that I should be able to do this with pivot table functionality.

Comment: Do a second Pivot table without the Payment Type, only the years for the rows?

Comment: @ScottCraner Unfortunately, the payment types are essential information that needs to be included and I would like to avoid adding a second pivot table to display the Totals.

Comment: Can you reverse the order of your payment type fields and years fields and then adjust for grand totals that way? Or are you looking for the existing result to also include the *requested* result?

Comment: @TotsieMae - I am looking for the existing result to include the requested result.